# how to center text a tag on div?

Tags: html, css

I want to center the text link in the div class `.nav-tab` I add `padding:0 auto;` but it not help allso I add `text-align:center;` and still it is not work.
thanks for any help.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/zCXMv/2/)

```
<nav id="main-nav-wrap">
<ul id="main-nav">
    <li class="">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="nav-tab">

           <a href="/"> Home </a>
          </div>
             <div class="tooltip">
             </div>
        </div>
    </li>
            <li class="">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="nav-tab">
            <a href="/"> abput</a>
            </div>
             <div class="tooltip">
             </div>
             </div>
    </li>
             <li class="">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="nav-tab">
            <a href="/"> contact</a>
            </div>
             <div class="tooltip">
             </div> </div>
    </li>
        </ul>
```

​

```
    #main-nav-wrap {
    width:200px;
    height:60px;

    margin:50px 0 0 10px;
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#main-nav{
    width:196px;
    height:60px;
    top:50px;
    margin:0 ;
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.inner{
    width:63px;
    height:58px;
      border:1px solid green;
    float:left;
}

.nav-tab{
     width:50px;
    height:58px;
    background-color: #BF87D1;
    margin:0 auto;
   }
.nav-tab a{
    vertical-align:-18px;

}
​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, understand that it's not valid to define `padding: 0 auto;` -- `auto` isn't an acceptable value for `padding`. Adding `text-align: center;` to `.nav-tab` really seems to fix the issue: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/zCXMv/6/).

Answer (score 4):

Just add:

```
.nav-tab {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this:

```
.nav-tab {
    background-color: #BF87D1;
    height: 58px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; /* HERE */
    width: 50px;
}
```

And it worked.